# Why does CSS styling distort my Google maps zooming?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a working version

http://jsfiddle.net/tH78C/

Here is a broken version (Zooming widget is no longer properly displayed) with Bootstrap styling

http://jsfiddle.net/3sjAU/

Why does it break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Bootstrap.css **line 69** `max-width: 100%;` is causing the issue.

```
img {
max-width: 100%; <--
vertical-align: middle;
border: 0;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

You can remove it and if needed again just specify a new class `.newclass {max-width:100%}` and add it to the image.

Answer (score 11):

You can also fix this for individual maps e.g.:

```
.googleMapContainer img {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This is a much more portable answer, particularly when you don't have control over the bootstrap source (like using a CDN).

Comment: This is more elegant than fiddling with the bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a slight variation on what was listed here.

```
.gm-style img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify a new class just copy this code

```
.angular-google-map img {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```